# What is the most efficient method to copy a linked server table into a SQL Server Database?

Tags: sql-server

I need to copy a table located on a linked server in my database. The Source Table has around 55 million records.

I have tried the "Select INTO" method (T-SQL codes) but the task fails after running for around 2 hours with a "communication link" error.

What would be the best method to accomplish this task?

Comment: Structuring the query as something that can be “batched” is likely advisable, regardless of actual copy mechanism. This will depend on available (hopefully clustered) indexing and other table usage characteristics. Then, eg, one can copy a million rows 55 times, and resume should there be a connection or other process error. (Batch sizes of 1/10M are likely more reasonable, and lead to more fine-grains progress reporting, depending on various factors.)

Comment: Alternatively (although it’s own can of worms), since this is SQL Server, set up a one time source -> target [replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication) publication and subscription. This may require that the source table has a rowguidcol defined, or other requirements, which may or may not be practical. (There are like a bajillion replication modes. Only slight sarcasm.)

Comment: Is this one-time operation or you need to have these target and source tables in sync? If this is one-time shot, you could try exporting the source table into .sql file via [right click] on the source DB -> Tasks -> Generate Scripts -> Select specific DB objects -> Select the table you want -> click Advanced button  and look for "Types of data to script" option. Customise the rest of the wizard according to your needs and then, try to import the .sql file on target server via commandline through SQLCMD. This, unlike SSMS shouldn't crash. Another, slightly more complex option is SSIS.

Comment: Is the linked server another SQL Server? Can you access it directly, or only via the linked server? Is the table indexed in a way that would allow batching? (Such as an ever-increasing `IDENTITY` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method1:
In my experience the fastest method would be:

1. Copy only the structure of the source to the target.
2. Dump the table contents to single CVS (TXT) files.
3. Load the text files with "Load data..."

If you use NAVICAT software, you can go through all these steps as a wizard.

Method2:
You can use NAVICAT software.

1. By establishing a connection.
2. In your connection, go to the database and right-click on the table and select the copy option.
3. Select the Copy option and paste it in the destination database.

This method shows you the amount of data transfer as a percentage

Comment: Thanks. Any pointers on how to copy the structure of the source table to the target database?

Comment: If you are using Management Studio, you can right-click on the table and export the 'Create script' And if you are using the NAVICAT, right-click on your table and select the Dump SQL file option and click on 'Structure only' .